# shopify.Article.find(blog_id=xxx, limit=50, page=zzz) returns duplicate articles

Tags: python, shopify

I have 221 articles. The code below returns 221 articles but duplicate, only 169 unique articles.

```
existing_articles = []
for i in xrange(1, 6):
    existing_artciles.extend(shopify.Article.find(blog_id=the_blog.id, limit=50, page=i))
len(existing_articles)
# 211
len(set([a.id for a in existing_articles]))
# 169
```

How can I get all articles (non-duplicate) in a blog?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured this out, but my best guess is that you don't actually have 5 pages of Articles. When you specify a page that's greater than the last page, you simply get the last page back, which would result in duplicate Articles.

The best thing to do is get the count of the Articles first, then use that to determine the total number of pages, and use that in your `xrange` function. Here it is in a function:

```
def get_all_articles():
    article_count = shopify.Article.count()

    articles = []
    if article_count > 0:
        for page in xrange(1, ((article_count-1) // 50) + 2):
            articles.extend( shopify.Article.find(page=page) )

    return articles
```

You can go a few steps further and genericize this to handle any countable shopify resource:

```
def get_all_of_resource(resource, **kwargs):
    resource_count = resource.count(**kwargs)

    resources = []
    if resource_count > 0:
        for page in xrange(1, ((resource_count-1) // 250) + 2):
            arguments = kwargs
            arguments.update({"limit" : 250, "page" : page})
            resources.extend( resource.find(**arguments) )

    return resources
```

You'd use it like this:

```
shirts = get_all_of_resource(shopify.Product, product_type="T-Shirt")
```

As you can see, I've also added the ability to pass additional parameters to filter your results, and also request the max number of items per page (250).